# dplyr mutate does not work with column names "TRUE" and "FALSE"

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

When I use `reshape2`,
I am able to obtain a data frame with columns named `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
The problem comes when I am trying to use `dplyr`
to compute the proportion of `TRUE` values,
because `TRUE` refers to the logical value which becomes 1,
rather than the column named `TRUE`.

What is a natural way to fix this problem?

```
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)

transplants <- data.frame(donor_region = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    recipient_region = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)) %>%
    mutate(is_self = donor_region == recipient_region)

x <- ddply(transplants, .(donor_region, is_self), summarise,
    freq = length(is_self))
x %>% print

# Compute the proportion of transplants with is_self == TRUE
y <- dcast(x, donor_region ~ is_self, value.var = 'freq') %>%
    mutate(true_proportion = TRUE / (FALSE + TRUE))
y %>% print

# What I get:
#   donor_region FALSE TRUE true_proportion
# 1            1     1    2               1
# 2            2     1    2               1

# What I want to get:
#   donor_region FALSE TRUE true_proportion
# 1            1     1    2       0.6666667
# 2            2     1    2       0.6666667
```

Comment: Can you use backticks like `\`TRUE\`` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Your suggestion works. Can you suggest it as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Although your comment doesn't answer the question directly, it does what I want to do in fewer lines of code. Could you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I have combined the answers given in the comments by @thelatemail and @jenesaisquoi since the comment section is not the best place to keep answers.

1. Using backticks (@thelatemail):

   ```
   dcast(x, donor_region ~ is_self, value.var = 'freq') %>%
     mutate(true_proportion = `TRUE` / (`FALSE` + `TRUE`))
   ```
2. Using weighted mean (@jenesaisquoi):

   ```
   x %>% group_by(donor_region) %>% summarise(tp = weighted.mean(is_self, freq))
   ```

Comment: If you combined answers, then this should be a CV probably.